# Body Styling Showing When Printing amcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs, amcharts

I am working on a project which includes an amcharts.com chart with a watermark/overlay image (e.g., as discussed here: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/adding-logo-watermark-exported-chart/).  The chart is included in a div on a page with body styling (e.g., a background, a box-shadow, etc.).  When printing the chart using the export item "Print," the resulting print includes the body styling (e.g., the background and box shadow).  However, I would like it to print without these items (e.g., similar to the "JPG" export item in the "Download as..." sub-menu).

An example can be found here: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/dc7015c33872771cf6e45e7752eaffe3.  To see the effect, print the chart (using the "Print" item of the export menu at the top-right of the chart) after adding the following CSS to the top of the existing CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #999;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #444;
}
```

On a Windows 10 machine, the effect is most noticeable in Firefox.  In Chrome, the background is not visible but the box-shadow is visible if "margin: 0px;" is removed from the html/body CSS.

The background and box-shadow can be removed by altering the body styling using javascript (removing the background and box-shadow before printing and re-adding after), but this causes objectionable flashing.  Is it possible to just exclude the body (or its styling) from the printing altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply CSS to a document when it is in print mode, you can use the `print` media query and write every changes you want to happen (`@media print { ... }`

```
@media print { 
   body {
     background-color: transparent;
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
   }
}
```

Comment: That is what I was referring to in the last paragraph re altering the body styling

Comment: wrap this inside `@media print { ... }`

Comment: @Aziz It worked.  Thank you.  If you post this an an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @bryman79 I just edited Rudi's answer since it is valid. Rudi simply didn't include the query rule in the code.